# Doing a series of operations on every subset of the data obtained from a dataframe

Tags: r

This is a question of a noob in 'R' world. I tried searching and there were quite a few solutions that came close (e.g aggregate, by, etc), but I lacked the understanding to apply it to my problem. Would really appreciate if someone can guide me in a more detailed way.

**Hypothetical Dataset**

```
Name    Wheels  Color   Mileage seat_capacity
1        2      Red      70         2
2        3      Black    60         7
3        4      Blue     12         5
4        4      White    15         6
5        3      Yellow   45         6
6        2      Green    70         2
7        3      Silver   45         6
8        6      Silver   5          4
9        14     Red      12         2
10       2      Black    70         7
11       4      Blue     70         5
12       3      White    60         6
13       4      Yellow   12         6
14       4      Green    15         2
```

I have initially created subsets of data based on color using split.

```
color <- split(df,df$color)
```

For each of the subsets created I would be doing more operations e.g

- finding the vehicles with highest mileage among the vehicles with lowest number of wheels in each subset.....etc

I have written all the rules pertaining to the later half as well. I am struggling to find a way where I can *run all the operations on each of the subset* in the variable color.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `lapply` to loop through each element of color. write a function that returns the stuff you want for a subset of data. `myOutput <- lapply(color, myFunction)`. Where `myFunction` is you user defined function.

Comment: @Imo  what I intend to do is,  apply a set of steps on each subset and get an output which is again a list. In the end I would like to combine all the outputs. If I understood you correct, you mean to suggest that I create a function that contains all the series of operations I intend to do and then apply on each subset using lapply ?

Comment: @aosmith I wish I could share the authentic data but I cannot. However, what I have explained pretty much sums up what I want to achieve. BTW I have 2 million rows and 60 columns of data !!

Comment: @aosmith After creating subsets based on color; for each subset I need to  arrange the list in ascending order based on the number of wheels. Then find the vehicle with highest mileage for each of the wheel-based categories.

Comment: To pull out max mileage row for each color/wheel combination, dplyr possibility: `df %>% group_by(Color, Wheels) %>% slice(which.max(Mileage))`.  For very large datasets with many groups then you might want the equivalent data.table solution for time savings.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for suggestions. I have been able to implement your suggestions and it has worked wonderfully well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me and I would sincerely want to thank @Imo and @aosmith for guiding me.

Assume, I would want to first group the df based on colour and then group further by wheels and then within each such subgroup(wheels) pick top 2 vehicles based on Mileage. Used the dplyr library to achieve the same.

```
     my_list <- df %>% group_by(color, wheels) %>% top_n(2,Mileage)
```

HTH